# Garbage pixels along one edge of image in 3D view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, artifacts

My son is working on a project in which he is creating animations using 2D images. We are seeing pixels along the top edge of one of the images in the 3D view and when rendering. There are no pixels in the original image along that edge.

It seems like a bug to me but does anybody here have any ideas or suggestions for things to try?

It might be easier to see in this video: https://youtu.be/uXZaWCP41Yc

[image: The pixels along the top of the image in the scene do not exist in the actual PNG]

**Update**

I can see that the pixels rendered along the top of the image appear to be coming from the bottom of the image. I edited the image to add red and yellow pixels at the bottom and those pixels can be seen in the render along the top edge of the image.

[image]

The .blend file can be retrieved from the following link:
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5qwP1iY7X6PR2Vkdmw4MFJrZFk

Comment: Can you upload the .blend with the texture used? Did you try different png image (from another source?). It is certainly not a bug.

Comment: Hey Jan, thank you for your response. I'll update the post with the .blend and .png files. I have noticed that if I edit the image to add red and yellow pixels at the bottom of the image, they show up in the garbage pixels across the top of the image in the render.

Comment: Then maybe adjusting UV mapping could be enough to solve the problem? I often leave 1-2px margin between UV islands to prevent this kind of issues.

Comment: Yes, editing the UV map and moving the top-left and top-right corners down slightly resolves the issue. Thank you.